# JAVA - Implementing Stack using linkedlists

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

I am trying to implement the stack i.e., `DSAStack.java` using my linked list i.e., `DSALinkedList.java`

How do I do it? I think I am supposed to have `push()` perform an `insertFirst()` and `pop()` do a `peekFirst()` and `removeFirst()` to get the LIFO behaviour? and what about `isEmpty()`
and the other methods?

I am not sure, please help me out. A clear explanation with a code would be much appreciable. Thank you in advance!

Here is the `DSAStack.java`

```
public class DSAStack implements Iterable {
    public static int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 100;

    private DSALinkedList list;
    private int           count;
    private Object[]      stack;

    public DSAStack() {
        count = 0;
        stack = new Object[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
}

public DSAStack(int maxCapacity) {
    count = 0;
    stack = new Object[maxCapacity];
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        boolean empty = (count == 0);   
        return empty;   
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        boolean full = (count == stack.length);
        return full;            
    }

    public void push(Object value) {
        if (isFull())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Stack is full");
        else
            stack[count] = value;

        count++;
    }

    public Object pop() {
        Object topVal = top();
        count--;

        return topVal;
    }

    public Object top() {
        Object topVal;

        if (isEmpty()) 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Stack is empty");
        else
            topVal = stack[count-1];

        return topVal; 
    }

    public Iterator iterator() {
        return list.iterator();
    }
}
```

AND here is the `DSALinkedList.java`

```
import java.util.*;

public class DSALinkedList {
    public DSAListNode head;
    public DSAListNode tail;
    Object[] newValue;

    public DSALinkedList() {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    public void insertFirst(Object newValue){
        DSAListNode newNd;
        newNd = new DSAListNode(newValue);

        if (head == null) {
            head = newNd;
            tail = newNd;   
        } else {
            newNd.setNext(head);
            head = newNd;
        }
    }

    public void insertLast(Object newValue){
        DSAListNode newNd;
        newNd = new DSAListNode(newValue);

        if(head == null){
            head = newNd;
        } else {
            tail.next = newNd;
            tail      = newNd;  
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (head == null);
    }

    public Object peekFirst(){
        Object nodeValue;

        if (head == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("head is empty");
        else 
            nodeValue = head.getValue();

        return nodeValue;
    }

    public Object peekLast(){
        Object nodeValue;

        if (head == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("head is empty");
        else
            nodeValue = tail.getValue();

        return nodeValue;
    }

    public Object removeFirst(){
        Object nodeValue;

        if (head == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("head is empty");
        } else {
            nodeValue = head.getValue();
            head      = head.getNext();
        }

        return nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DSAStack class is meant to be the interface between the user and linkedlist. So therefore the class provides the LIFO interface and forces it on the user. From here, it should hide the implementation from the linkedlist so the user doesn't have to worry about insertingLast or insertingFirst, they just want to insert.

So to answer your question. The DSAStack needs to perform the following actions:

> ```
> - size() -> returns int size
> - push(Object e) -> returns bool (able to be inserted)
> - pop() -> returns Object and removes it from linkedlist
> - peek() -> returns Object
> - isEmpty() -> returns bool if empty
> ```

Your DSAStack isn't meant to hold any data. So you don't need the count or stack variable. Instead, we need to store these inside the DSALinkedList class. DSAStack should therefore instantiate a DSALinkedList object, pass the maxCapacity, and initiate the object.

When the user says that they want to use pop() on DSAStack, the class then needs to tell DSALinkedList, hey! I want to pop one of your objects! Now DSALinkedList needs to implement the details here.

Rewriting your code would be like this:

```
    public DSAStack(int maxCapacity) {
        list = new DSALinkedList[maxCapacity];
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return list.isEmpty(); 
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return list.isFull();          
    }

    public void push(Object value) {
        list.insertLast(value);
    }

    public Object pop() {
        return list.removeLast();
    }

    public Object top() {
        return list.peekLast();
    }

    public Iterator iterator() {
        return list.iterator();
    }
}
```